# Error de-serializing object graph in Blazor client which uses custom converters derived from JsonConverter

Tags: json.net, blazor

I want to de-serialize an object graph in my blazor client when it is returned from a blazor server-side api method (similar to the weatherforecasts sample). I need to use my own de-serialization method with custom converters based upon JsonConverter because my object graph has composite objects which implement the same interface.

Everything works outside of my blazor project and if I return the object graph as a string to the client it has been serialized properly. It's the de-serialization that is not working.

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter' not found.
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x20812e8 + 0x0032c> in <f4072889680a4c139ae7f58d7e8832a7>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) <0x2080d18 + 0x000c8> in <f4072889680a4c139ae7f58d7e8832a7>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x267adf8 + 0x00016> in <f4072889680a4c139ae7f58d7e8832a7>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.SecurityUtils.SecureCreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Boolean allowNonPublic) <0x267ad28 + 0x00092> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.SecurityUtils.SecureCreateInstance (System.Type type) <0x2678c10 + 0x00008> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.CreateInstance (System.Type objectType, System.Type callingType) <0x2677f58 + 0x00034> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.SearchIntrinsicTable (System.Collections.Hashtable table, System.Type callingType) <0x26774e8 + 0x002e8> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider+ReflectedTypeData.GetConverter (System.Object instance) <0x266a3b8 + 0x00180> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.GetConverter (System.Type type, System.Object instance) <0x2669d30 + 0x00016> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter () <0x2669a88 + 0x0003e> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter (System.Type type) <0x2665718 + 0x00010> in <19bbec7b522743e889bff711c7b96bc3>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.CanTypeDescriptorConvertString (System.Type type, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter& typeConverter) <0x265a220 + 0x0000a> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CanConvertToString (System.Type type) <0x265a010 + 0x0000a> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) <0x260ec98 + 0x0013c> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) <0x260e2b8 + 0x000a2> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe (System.Type type) <0x260dda0 + 0x00034> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (System.Collections.IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id) <0x27f8df0 + 0x000c8> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) <0x27eac60 + 0x001ac> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bce40 + 0x000d0> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) <0x27cd020 + 0x00270> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ObjectConstructor`1[T] creator, System.String id) <0x27d4980 + 0x00142> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract objectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) <0x27c0418 + 0x0006a> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bdb80 + 0x002c2> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bce40 + 0x000b0> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (System.Collections.IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id) <0x27f8df0 + 0x0034e> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) <0x27eac60 + 0x001ac> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bce40 + 0x000d0> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) <0x27cd020 + 0x00270> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ObjectConstructor`1[T] creator, System.String id) <0x27d4980 + 0x00142> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract objectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) <0x27c0418 + 0x0006a> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bdb80 + 0x002c2> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) <0x27bce40 + 0x000b0> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) <0x260daa8 + 0x001b0> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) <0x25f1928 + 0x000ac> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) <0x25f1258 + 0x00010> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) <0x25f84e8 + 0x00076> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) <0x25f7c70 + 0x0000c> in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Localization.Jliff.Graph.Converter.Deserialize (System.String json) [0x0006f] in E:\Dev\DotNet\JliffEditor\JliffEditor.Jliff\Serialization\Converter.cs:76 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at JliffEditor.Client.Pages.Editor.OnInitAsync () [0x00096] in E:\Dev\DotNet\JliffEditor\JliffEditor.Client\Pages\Editor.razor:46 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x206d928 + 0x00160> in <13ab8f8dacb6489b93c9655168c56037>:0 
blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x224efa0 + 0x000fe> in <13ab8f8dacb6489b93c9655168c56037>:0
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to approach solving this.

**EDIT**

Thinking that I might switch Json Serializers, I followed links through the post: [Announcing .NET Core 3.0 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-5/) to the [System.Text.Json Docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/docs/SerializerProgrammingModel.md) which would indicate that polymorphic behaviour is not supported. Off in search of other alternatives, perhaps [TinyJSON](https://github.com/pbhogan/TinyJSON)...

**EDIT II**

TinyJSON works to a point. In transmission the data includes extra `@type` properties which rubs on my purist side but hey. Leaving the question unanswered in case there is a simple solution to being able to use Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve the problem by including a reference to your converter class(es) in your client side code.

I had a similar problem with JSON deserialization in Blazor client.  In my case, the 'constructor on type xxx not found' error was for the `Int32Converter` and `StringConverter` classes.  Including a reference to each of those classes in my client side code allowed me to get past the issue (I put them in my ConfigureServices method).

Seems like the code optimizer is too eager to strip out unused classes/methods.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1897) on this a few months ago but there has been no movement on it to date.  The issue's description has some more details if you are interested.

Incidentally, there are other similar problems I have seen before that weren't so easy to hack my way past.  I am hitting a problem with a MissingMethodException on System.Math.Min as I write this...